# "end" parameter in "print" function not working in python

Tags: python, loops

I'm wondering why end =" " is not working here. Could you help me?

```
import sys
num1 = int(input())
num2 = int(input())
sum_even_pos = 0
sum_odd_pos = 0

for n in range (num1, num2 + 1):
    n = str(n)
    for i in range(0, 6):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            sum_odd_pos = int(n[0]) + int(n[2]) + int(n[4])
        else:
            sum_even_pos = int(n[1]) + int(n[3]) + int(n[5])
    if sum_odd_pos == sum_even_pos:
        print(n, end =" ")
        print()
```

tried end=" " and expected no new line after each print()

Comment: Are you certain it's `print(n, end =" ")` printing new line and not `print()`?

Comment: You have another `print` there causing newlines.

Answer (score 0):

A blank `print()` statement (last line) would bring a newline anyway